# 2 integer arrays or dictionary - What to choose for storing height and width of image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get thumbnail for the original image, for requested widths and heights with the help of generic handler. But I want to authorize requests to some limited set of widths and heights. 
ex. 18*18, 98*94, 117*113 etc.
Anything out of these predefined sets would be treated as bad request.
So I want to save these predefined set of height and width in some kind of data structure. So that when I get request for some width and height, I can check if this belongs to predefined set. If not, I can ignore the request.. Something like:

```
     if(PreferredWidths.Contains(requestedWidth).Index == PreferredHeights.Contains(requestedHeight).Index)
{
           // Process request.. 
}
```

This was some logic, I could come up, which I want to convert in a code( Anything better is appreciated). I am not sure which data structures I should use for  storing set of widths and heights. Is there any better approach, that I can use for same purpose. As any fake user can change the source of image from browser by just changing parameters of handler url (abc.ashx?Id=123&width=20&height=30). Internally, I am creating thumbnails, saving them on disk and returning urls of the same. I dont want to do this stuff, if set of requested width and height is not legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) struct in System.Drawing.  You could just store a list of Sizes and then use:

```
var ValidSizes = new List<Size> 
{
    new Size(18, 18),
    new Size(98, 94),
    new Size(117, 113)
};

if(ValidSizes.Any(p => p.Width == requestedWidth && p.Height == requestedHeight))
{
    // Process Request
}
```

Comment: Why not just `if (MyStoredSizes.Contains(new Size(requestedWidth,requestedHeight)))` ?

Comment: Yup.. this will do. It will also add some more readability to code.

Answer (score 2):

```
IList<Tuple<double, double>> supported = new List<>...


// search usign LINQ
var found = supported.Where(new LambdaComparer<Tuple<double, double>>((s1, s2) =>
     { s1.Item1 == s2.Item1 && s2.Item2 == s2.Item2 }));
```

See for LambdaComparer in intrawebs, I would  recommend John Skeet's one.

Comment: Why a LambdaComparer? Why not just `supported.Contains(Tuple.Create(requestedWidth,requestedHeight))`?